# Export Java Class from Path

Tags: java, class, export

I want to export Code out of my Eclipse Project, only knowing the path to. 
The Path looks like

> net.sf.jabref.gui.ImportInspectionDialog.ImportInspectionDialog(JabRefFrame,BasePanel,String[],String,boolean)

How can i afford to export the Code of this url, into a new File ?

Best regards

Comment: Given this code is not yours, you can't export it. You only can use the librairy in your project

Comment: Thats not right. I got the SOurcecode sicne the Project is opensource. I just want to know how to export the code from paths like the one above, into another file automated, cause i need to do it with hundreds of urls like this. They all should be exported automated for my needs

Answer (score 1):

[Ask your favorite search engine](https://www.google.de/search?q=net.sf.jabref.gui.importinspectiondialog) and you will see that the code for jabref is available at github. Take a look at the code of that class [here](https://github.com/rodrigorgs/jabref-2.9.2/blob/master/src/java/net/sf/jabref/gui/ImportInspectionDialog.java).

If you use maven to manage/import your dependencies, you can select "download sources" in the eclipse maven settings. That causes the classes to always come with the source code when available.

I don't understand what you mean by "export", but you can copy the code to your own java file.

Comment: Hey
I know the Sourcecode is available online, it was jsut an example. I want to know how to extract code from urls like the one above, in generall and automated. Searched for it in google, but didnt fidn anything thats matching my needs

how can i access the file with java, to copy the code ? i dont know how to root a path like this